# exclude functions from google compiler

Tags: javascript, clojure, clojurescript, google-closure-compiler

I have the following in a cljs file

```
(defn load-coords []
  (let [svg (.getSVGDocument (. js/document (getElementById "game-board")))
        s (ef/from svg
      :coords "#circles circle"
      (fn [circle]
        {:x (.-baseVal.value (.-cx circle))
         :y (.-baseVal.value (.-cy circle))
         }))]
.....
```

When I try to compile the project using `:optimisations :advanced` I get the following error message when running the project js in the browser

> TypeError: document.getElementById(...).eh is not a function

Seems like `.getSVGDocument` might be getting "mangled" in the compiler is there any way to "exclude" things like this from happening other than **externs** of **:optimisation :simple**?

I'm not even sure how to include it in the externs as it is part of the js element specifications...like how do I write that in the externs?

Answer (score 2):

`getSVGDocument` is not part of the externs in Closure-compiler. However, you can provide your own extern to correct the problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/21122560/1211524

You'll need to know what type of element you will be adding the definition to. For instance, if you wanted to add it to the `HTMLElement` type, it might look something like:

```
/**
 * @fileoverview
 * @externs
 */

/**
 * @return {HTMLElement} this should really be SVGElement -
 *    but closure-compiler doesn't recognize that type
 */
HTMLElement.prototype.getSVGDocument = function();
```

Comment: Well that's kind of odd isn't it? getSVGDocument is part of the HTML/ SVG Element specification...not so?

Comment: Yes it is part of the specification, but the built in cljs externs do not cover the  full specification sadly.

Comment: The externs for the compiler are hand crafted. There just hasn't been a demand for the SVG externs and nobody has submitted them as a pull request.