# How can I tell Closure compiler that something exists in a separate file?

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

I have a project which includes `library.js` and `mycode.js`. My code includes

```
let x = new LibraryObject ();
```

I tried running `mycode.js` through [Google Closure](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/) which complains

```
ERROR - variable LibraryObject is undeclared
```

when the `-W VERBOSE` flag is given.

I could concatenate the two files into `libraryandmycode.js` but I want to keep them separate because reasons. I tried declaring `LibraryObject` in `mycode.js` but then I get an "illegal redeclared variable" error.

Without modifying `library.js`, can I add something to `mycode.js` which will establish that `LibraryObject` exists, but without redeclaring it?

This causes no problems in the browser but I want validation to pass for each file separately as well as when they're taken together.

The criteria is that no errors are produced under strict interpretation whether either of the two scripts are parsed individually, or when both are taken together.

Is this possible?

Comment: require('./library') does not work?

Comment: [This is not Node.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9901082/what-is-this-javascript-require)

Comment: Have you tried including the first one using `<script src="library.js"></src>`, then the second with `<script src="mycode.js"></src>` in your HTML?

Comment: The issue isn't getting it to work in the browser, it's getting it pass cleanly through minifiers/validators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extern files are used to provide type information to the compiler for symbols that are not included in the compilation. Extern files are valid JavaScript, but only contain type definitions - don't try to use the library itself.

Use the `--externs` flag to pass an extern file to the compiler.

The [compiler projects hosts several extern files](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/tree/master/contrib/externs). It's also possible to [write your own](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21122560/1211524).

If you are looking for an example, the [jQuery externs](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/blob/master/contrib/externs/jquery-1.12_and_2.2.js) are well maintained.

Answer (score -1):

This is how it works for me.

```
java -jar closure-compiler-v20160713.jar
The compiler is waiting for input via stdin.
let a= new Test ();
^Z
var a=new Test;
```

I definitely dont have Test() declared. Are you using a different version?

Comment: You missed out the `-W VERBOSE` argument (to be fair, so did I, question edited).