# Closure Compiler: renaming of variable and its properties

Tags: javascript, closures, google-closure-compiler

I am using closure compiler for my project.

One of my project files has an declaration like :

```
var data = window.somedata || {};
```

The file returns this `object` which is being used by other files. Closure compiler renames all the properties of this data `object` (in advanced mode) when it is used.

How to tell the compiler not to rename any property related to this variable?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-tutorial3#externs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can prevent renaming by either using quotes for every property access:

```
console.log(data['myprop'])
```

Or by using externs. Externs are separate files that define types.

**extern**

```
/** @typedef {{prop1: string, prop2: boolean}} */
var FileObj;
```

**source**

```
var data = window.somedata || /** @type {FileObj} */ ({});
```

[More about writing externs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21122560/1211524)

Comment: Is it possible to restrict closure compiler from renaming the properties of the FileObj by just mentioning the object  and not all its properties and sub-properties explicitly?

Comment: No - you must specify every property as external to block renaming.